# Two interdependent observables but keep both, how to implement?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my application I have to fill two observables in my component. This component belongs to the route '`/profiles/:customerNickname`'.

One observable is the customer itself.
For this I use the nickname parameter of the URL. The other is his purchases made.
The second is based on the first because I use the ID of the found customer.

I'm not familiar with RXJS well enough, but I'm sure that the following can be simplified.

But how?

```typescript
customer$: Observable<Customer>;
purchases$: Observable<Purchase[]>;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private customerService: CustomerService
) {
  //First: The Customer
  this.customer$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      const nickName = params.get('customerNickname');
      return this.customerService.getCustomerByNickname(nickName);
    })
  );

  //Second: The Purchases which needs the Customer
  this.purchases$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      const nickName = params.get('customerNickname');
      return this.customerService.getCustomerByNickname(nickName);
    }),
    switchMap((customer: Customer) => {
      return this.customerService.getPurchasesForCustomer(customer.id);
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply use first observable in the logic for building the 2nd one

```
  this.purchases$ = this.customer$.pipe(
    switchMap((customer: Customer) => {
      return this.customerService.getPurchasesForCustomer(customer.id);
    })
  );
```

however I suspect you are going to use both of the observable somewhere (for example in the template). in this case, considering the nature of observables several requests for the customer data would be made instead of just one. to fix that some sharing should be added to the first stream

```
  this.customer$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      const nickName = params.get('customerNickname');
      return this.customerService.getCustomerByNickname(nickName);
    }),
    shareReplay(1), // this will ensure that all of the dependants 
    // will use one source, instead of creating new source for every consumer
  );
```